# Unable to send ETH from contract to other contract while runing on hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

i am forking mainnet and using instances of uniswapV2 and WETH contract,
I am created my own contrat in which i call the uniswap functions.everything is working fine but i am unable to transfer ETH from contract to uniswap contract.

this my testcase code where i call the function:

```
// calling getTokens functions
    const getTokenCall = await Splitter.connect(signer1).getTokens({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});
    getTokenCall.wait();
    console.log(getTokenCall);
```

here is the line where i am getting error.

```
payable(Router_address).transfer(USDCeth);
```

this is an error what i am getting :

```
   Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d)
    at SwapSplitter.getTokens (contracts/Splitter.sol:72)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1773:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:466:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1504:18)
    at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:118:18)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

this is full function :

```
function getTokens() payable external returns (bool){

        // size of uint256 is 8 bytes (256 bites)
        uint256 currentAmount = msg.value;
        uint256 USDCeth; 
        uint256 USDTeth;
        uint256 DAIeth;

         // storing the values recevied.
        _balances[msg.sender] += currentAmount;

        console.log("Value recevied :");
        console.log(currentAmount);

        // eth calculation to split
        DAIeth = currentAmount / 2; // to split 50% of eth for dai or token 3.
        console.log("amount for DAI :");
        console.log(DAIeth);
        uint256 percentage = currentAmount / 10;
        //         getting 10% * percentage we want
        USDCeth = percentage * 2;
        console.log("amount for USDC :");
        console.log(USDCeth);
        USDTeth = percentage * 3;
        console.log("amount for USDT :");
        console.log(USDTeth);
        /*here my transaction gets failed while sending eth */
        payable(Router_address).transfer(USDTeth);
        //console.log("A");
        UniswapRouter02Interface(Router_address).swapExactETHForTokens{ value: msg.value}(1, getPathForETHtoUSDC(), msg.sender, block.timestamp + 200); 
        //console.log("b");
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Divisions are tricky, can you print percentage too to see if its 0.

Comment: Also that is not how you send Ethereum or use the router, please include a description of the use case you are trying to implement

Comment: i have consle log the calculation to check
`Value recevied :
1000000000000000000
amount for DAI :
500000000000000000
amount for USDC :
200000000000000000
amount for USDT :
300000000000000000`